# Is this possible with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, replace

Something like this:

```
/[abcd]/[efgh]/
```

The idea is that `a` will get replaced with `e`, `b` with `f`, `c` with `g` and so on.

Ideally, this should be language independent. If that isn't possible, I have an alternate solution (because this regex is generated by some code, I can make one for each of the possible replacements).

Comment: No, not with "normal" regexps =p

Comment: I was trying to come up with an answer longer than "No, that doesn't work". I guess I'll go with a comment.

Comment: you should say what your language is next time. If it supports associative arrays, you can map "a" with "e" etc. assoc["a"]="e".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In perl, `tr` performs character replacement:

```
tr/abcd/efgh/
```

Will do what your example suggests.

Comment: You mean "a cold day" becomes "e golh hey"?

Comment: Yes. That is what `tr` does. You can even use range shorthands - forex `tr/a-z/A-Z/` will convert characters to uppercase.

Comment: tr does exactly this. rare one-to-one mapping between question and feature. +1

Answer (score 2):

In sed, the `y///` expression does just that.

It's also a synonym for `tr///` in perl

Answer (score 0):

In Python its possible with passing Lambda function to re.sub

```
>>> import re
>>> d={"a":"e","b":"f","c":"g","d":"h"}
>>> re.sub("[abcd]",lambda x:d[x.group(0)],"abcd")
'efgh'
```

Normally, just mapping "a" to "e", is not really useful.

It will be more useful like following case, when you want to change a,b,c,d to e,f,g,h when "x" is before those. It can be done with one regex.

```
>>> re.sub("(?<=x)[abcd]",lambda x:d[x.group(0)],"xaxbxcxdaabbccdd")
>>>'xexfxgxhaabbccdd'
```

Comment: Added one more case, It could be more useful than [abcd] to [efgh] example.

Answer (score 0):

well, with Python, shouldn't have to use regex as well

```
>>> import string
>>> FROM="abcd"
>>> TO="efgh"
>>> table=string.maketrans(FROM,TO)
>>> print "a cold day".translate(table)
e golh hey
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it in a regex: some languages can have an expression as the right hand side of a regexp, so maybe something like (Perl):

> $foo =~ s/x([a-d])/"x".chr(ord($1)+4)/e

would do the trick, although it *is* kind of awful, and it probably not really what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP this can be done by passing arrays in the `preg_replace`.

```
$outputText = preg_replace($arraySource, $arrayTarget, $inputText);

$arraySource[0] is replaced by $arrayTarget[0]

$arraySource[1] is replaced by $arrayTarget[1]

$arraySource[2] is replaced by $arrayTarget[2]

      .                              .

      .                              .

      .                              .

      .                              .
```

and so on.

Comment: Or using `strtr($str, 'abcd', 'efgh')` (in this specific case).

Answer (score 0):

There's a UNIX command 'tr' which does this, as an addition to the Perl and Python answers...